# Как загрузить данные из MS SQL Server в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, база-данных

На компьютере установлен сервер баз данных MS SQL Server. В базе "COKO" лежит таблица "Школы". Помогите начинающему отобразить данную таблицу у себя в DataGridView. 
Подключение к серверу в VS я "вроде" сделал:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать binding DataGridView c этой таблицей.

Что-то вроде этого:

```
DataGridView dgv = что_то;
string connectionString = "...";
string sqlQuery = "требуемый SQL-запрос";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
da.Fill(ds, "имя_вашей_таблицы");
connection.Close();
dgv.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "имя_вашей_таблицы";
```